# How to make a class model in .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I make class model in .net core whose output is like this?

```
   {
 "devices": [
    "router",
    "cable"
  ]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question need more details  and clarity

Answer (score -1):

You can model your class after your json like this:

```
class AnyName
{
    public string[] devices { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use attributes to make the json serialized or deserialized to look like you want to if you are using NewtonSoft JSON:

```
public class AnyName
{
    [JsonProperty("devices ")]
    public string[] AnyOtherName { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you are using the Microsoft System.Text.Json variant:

```
public class AnyName
{
    [JsonPropertyName("devices ")]
    public string[] AnyOtherName { get; set; }
}
```

To make it conform to Entity Frameworks Code first model:

```
public class AnyName
{
    [JsonPropertyName("devices ")]
    public virtual ICollection<string> AnyOtherName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt Can make it to be [Key] property since I need to use those string values inside another table (model class)?

Comment: I doubt you can make a List one of your [Key] properties for Entity Framework, since it's supposed to be... well... a unique key. Normally, that's a GUID, int, or at least string field. Not a list of fields.

Comment: Oh I understand. So I need to specify Id column no matter what.

Comment: Yes, you need to have one column that is a unique identifier. I doubt your list would be uniquely identifying, even if it were possible syntactically.

Comment: There is an error when I try to migrate this:The property 'Devices.deviceList' could not be mapped because it is of type 'string[]', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either

Comment: Looks like good solution, however, migration tells me that it can't be of type <string>, but when I make it to be <Posts> (which is my second table), it return null of tagList on GET api.

Comment: You should really not use the same model for your database and your REST API.